# Set up Jenkins to use Crowd's OpenID for SSO?

Tags: hudson, single-sign-on, openid, crowd, jenkins

Been trying to get Jenkins to work with Crowd's OpenID server so we can use single sign-on like with our Atlassian stuff (the Jenkins Crowd plugin can't do SSO).  Can't seem to find the proper OpenID URL to give Jenkins though.  Only one I can get from CrowdID is a per-user URL.  Is there a way to get a server-wide URL out of CrowdID for this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

see also:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9035

But I got with both crowd urls:

```
org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException: 0xa00: Authentication cannot continue: no discovery information provided.
```

The first that is like a valid endpoint is somewhat like crowdid.example.com/users/ but with that, I get the following message after login in CrowdID:

```
OpenID Verification Error
A request has been made to authenticate an OpenID identifier, different from the one you are logged in as. To use a different OpenID, log out and log in as a different user.
```

Will give Update if it is fixed here ;)

**Update**:
Atlassian is currently not supporting such a single-Endpoint. Hudson/Jenkins OpenIdSSO won't work!
The feature Request: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CWD-2470

**Update**:
This is fixed in [Crowd 2.6](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Crowd+2.6+Release+Notes), where the [endpoint URL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59277403#id-1.3WhatisanOpenIDURLoridentifier?-EndpointURLs) will end in `/op`, rather than `/users/username`.